# Testing XML input with Gherkin

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

How should I write Cucumber tests in Gherkin which test XML going into a system?

I had a chase-my-tail moment trying to figure out why my XML parser was throwing a "wrong closing tag" error when looking at something like this:

```
Scenario Outline:
  When I send this XML: <xml>
  Then my app says <hi>

  Examples:
    | xml                               | hi              |
    | <testing><hi>world</hi></testing> | BREAKIN' UR XML |
```

The Gherkin interpreter (within Ruby) looks at `<xml>` for the line were `xml = <testing><hi>world</hi></testing>` and substitutes `<hi>`, making the ultimate test:

```
Scenario:
  When I send this XML: <testing>BREAKIN' UR XMLworld</hi></testing>
  The my app says BREAKIN' UR XML
```

Obviously not what I'm trying to do!

This makes me think there's a better way to send larger but important snippets of code in the examples format (so that it won't be replaced by Gherkin's substitutions)

Any advice?

Comment: Is this a good candidate for a Gherkin test? I think such test should be readable by business people, but it seems this one is a bit too technical for that? I would probably translate this to something more like a business language; and use unit tests for this kind of tests?

Comment: Would business folks care what the XML looks like? This looks too low a level for a Cucumber test, or at least the Scenario part.

Comment: Sounds like there is a naive implementation for replacing the scenario outline parameters, which replaces the parameters one-by-one. Hence if the first parameter replacement introduced something that looks like a parameter it get replaced in the second parameter replacement. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature actually, but probably the result depends on the order of parameters. Try to change the examples table so that the <xml> column is the last one.